# reload a fragment android if exist else create it

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and android 2.3 version, so i wont if i click a button to create an instance of my fragment it verify his existance before, and in the case that it exist i should reload it and not create another instance.
This is the code that i use:

```
private void addNewFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, fragment, LEADERBOARD_FRAG_TAG);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    transaction.commit();
    }
```

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myFragment);
if(fragment == null){
 // create it
}
addNewFragment(fragment);
```